# .htaccess: Rewrite dynamic url with static url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to enter `http://localhost:81/admin/dashboard` in my browser but the request should be `http://localhost:81/admin/index.php?page=dashboard`.

The mod_rewrite is enabled and i tried this in the .htaccess but it didn't work. The .htaccess is located in htdocs/admin/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?page=$1  [NC]
```

Comment: Your regex in `RewriteRule` ends in a slash, but the path in the url you are using `http://localhost:81/admin/dashboard` does not. The regex will not match that url.

Comment: Thank you, I added the same RewriteRule without the slash and now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can match the trailing slash optionally  by adding a **?** next to it in the pattern :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1  [NC]
```